# How to remove comments from a file using "grep"?

Tags: sql, grep

I have an SQL file that I need to remove all the comments

```
-- Sql comment line
```

How can I achieve this in Linux using GREP or other tool?

Best Regards,

Comment: What about comments that don't start at the beginning of the line?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `grep` tool has a `-v` option which reverses the sense of the filter. For example:

```
grep -v pax people
```

will give you all lines in the `people` file that *don't* contain `pax`.

An example is:

```
grep -v '^ *-- ' oldfile >newfile
```

which gets rid of lines with only white space preceding a comment marker. It *won't* however change lines like:

```
select blah blah -- comment here.
```

If you wanted to do that, you would use something like `sed`:

```
sed -e 's/ --.*$//' oldfile >newfile
```

which edits each line removing any characters from `" --"` to the end of the line.

Keep in mind you need to be careful with finding the string `" --"` in *real* SQL statements like (the contrived):

```
select ' -- ' | colm from blah blah blah
```

If you have these, you're better off creating/using an SQL parser rather than a simple text modification tool.

---

A transcript of the `sed` in operation:

```
pax$ echo '
...> this is a line with -- on it.
...> this is not
...> and -- this is again' | sed -e 's/ --.*$//'

this is a line with
this is not
and
```

For the `grep`:

```
pax$ echo '
  -- this line starts with it.
this line does not
and -- this one is not at the start' | grep -v '^ *-- '

this line does not
and -- this one is not at the start
```

Comment: Hi, I have tested the SED command but is not deleting the lines that contain "--". The GREP command only remove few line ftom the beginning of the file.

Comment: @André: then I'm not sure you're using them right. I've added a couple of transcripts to the end of my answer to show the test cases.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the sed command as `sed -i '/\-\-/d' <filename>`

Comment: It work both ways. It can be written as sed -i '/--/d' <filename>. I admit I was thinking that '-' might be a special character We can also do an inplace changes in the file with the -i option.

Comment: I had to add the backslashes to make this work on MacOS.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `sed` on shell:

```
sed -e "s/(--.*)//" sql.filename
```

Comment: Why the `g`? If you're matching *everything* after `--`, then there can only be one occurrence per line.